Is there a way to skip several blocks or slots forward at anchor test?
I want to call the instruction which makes a change at the account's states after some time passed (so after some slots passed). The logic is related to the passed slots, so I want to test this logic. I've tried to see if there's some related functions at anchor.provider.connection, but couldn't find any. Is there a way to skip several blocks or slots forward at anchor test?

You are probably using mocha tests with chai assertion. Thats the standart in anchor test. Anchor is starting a local validator for you where it deploys your program and then runs the tests against it. You can see whats actually called in the anchor toml.
I dont think you can skip forward blocks. You have a few options though:

You can just wait in the test frontend js a bit
You can use solana bank run time travel feature. Here is the docs:
https://kevinheavey.github.io/solana-bankrun/tutorial/#time-travel
https://github.com/kevinheavey/anchor-bankrun
Here is a working example of the time travel:
https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-game-preset/blob/main/program/jesttests/energy-refill-time.test.ts
and here a video explaining it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rut9l6nPZls

Basically you replace your anchor provider with the bankrun provider and then do smth like this:
    const currentClock = await client.getClock();
    context.setClock(
      new Clock(
        currentClock.slot,
        currentClock.epochStartTimestamp,
        currentClock.epoch,
        currentClock.leaderScheduleEpoch,
        BigInt(timestamp) + BigInt(60 * 11)
      )
    );


You can also do that with https://luzid.app/ but i havent tried that yet.

